# Is Facebook app visible if not registered in app center

Tags: android, facebook, release, facebook-authentication

I'm building android app with facebook sign-in option and I'm having trouble with understanding facebook app management.

In order to user facebook sign-in I had to create app in "facebook for developers". It's not a game, so I will not publish it in Facebook's app center. I wonder what happens when I mark app published. UI and docs suggests it will be visible to all facebook users, but I wonder how would users find it, if it's not in app center. Would have any effect, if I mark it published in Facebook and not have it ready

What am I missing?

Comment: _“but I wonder how would users find it, if it's not in app center”_ - via your own “marketing” - on your website, on your Facebook page, via ads, in Google play store, …

Comment: I understand that there are other way to advertise it. What I meant is whether facebook users will see published facebook app if it's not in app center. If not, then I can publish it even when it's not ready. Otherwise, I'd have to wait until is production-ready.

Comment: Can not be totally excluded that they might find it in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

you are not missing anything that's how facebook works

Comment: Does it mean that facebook users will not see it and I can safely publish it as noone will notice? That would be great, as I'd have one less place to worry about during final release :)